# Implementing the IMapper interface

Tags: petapoco

I have used PetaPoco in the past, decorating my objects with `[Column("{column name")]` attributes and so on. However, I'm trying to implement a "pure" domain model that has no knowledge of persistence and therefore no knowledge of PetaPoco's attributes.

The PetaPoco [blog](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/137/Long-Time-No-Post-and-PetaPoco-v5) mentions that there is an `IMapper` interface ("New Mapper API") that must be implemented in order to map objects to their tables without decorating the object's class. However, neither the blog post or the source code really explain what an implementation of `IMapper` is supposed to do.

If I simply want to map my domain entities to particular table, primary key, and column names, do I need to implement `IMapper` and how might I do so?

Comment: It looks like I may just switch to [NPoco's fluent mapping](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Fluent-Mappings-including-Conventional).

Answer (score 0):

There's more current information about mappers [here](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Mapping-Pocos). Basically, you have a choice of writing a class that implements `IMapper` or creating a descendant of `ConventionMapper` (which already implements `IMapper` and which offers more detailed hooks for customization). You can choose to write one mapper per type or one mapper per assembly.

`ConventionMapper` is already pretty smart about inferring table and column names from a type if you follow certain naming conventions (hence the name); sometimes it's enough to make a descendant that just has some alternate rules for `InflectColumnName()` and `InflectTableName()` and registering it for the whole assembly. But if you've got types where the field names really don't look anything like the table column names, then IMO you're better off implementing an `IMapper` per type from scratch (or inheriting from `StandardMapper`) and filling in all the details.